# c++ design with unique_ptr with custom deleter

Tags: c++, design-patterns, memory-management

I am writing a tree data structure. Each node has a fixed size so I use a fixed size allocator for allocating/deallocating `Node`. This gives me a headache:

```
struct Node {
  // other attributes ...
  std::array<std::unique_ptr<Node, CustomDeleter>, num_children> children_;
};
```

Since all allocations/deallocations of `Node` are managed by my custom `Alloc`, I can't use `std::unique_ptr<Node>` for child nodes, I have to ship custom deleter (associated with that allocator) to children.

But `Alloc` must know the type of `Node`, because `Alloc` is a fixed-size allocator for `Node`, it should be aware of `sizeof(Node)` and `alignof(Node)`.

But `Node` must know the type of `Alloc`, because `CustomDeleter` cannot be instantiated without `Alloc`! This is a circular depedency!

Have the C++ committee never considered about implementing a tree structure when they designed `std::unique_ptr<Node, Deleter>`? How can I resolve this problem?

ps. I can't use `std::allocator<Node>` because I should be able to use memory resource other than the default memory resource

Comment: When I looked into the STL (glibc++) I do not remember any container using unique_ptr inside, only raw pointers.  unique_ptr and others are more for application code. For low level programming stick with the basics.

Comment: What is `Alloc` really? And can `CustomDeleter` be a template which takes an `Alloc` as template argument? Or why not the two-argument [`std::unique_ptr` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) where you pass an instance to the deleter, which could have been initialized with knowledge of the allocator `Alloc`.

Comment: @MadFred turning back to the good old ```std::array<Node*>``` does not help me, because I should delete all children at ```~Node()``` to prevent memory leak anyway, and this deallocations should be managed by my custom ```Alloc```, so ```Node``` should be aware of ```Alloc```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude My ```CustomDeleter``` is actually ```Deleter<Alloc>```, its ```operator()``` does nothing more than ```alloc_.deallocate(ptr, sizeof(T));```

Comment: You should be able to make the code work by refactoring the code to occur in the following sequence: 1. Forward declaration of `Node`. 2. Declaration of `CustomDeleter`/ `Alloc`, not implementing the functions requiring the info about `Node` yet. 3. Class definition of `Node`. 4. Any function implementations missing from `CustomDeleter`/`Alloc`, adding the `inline` modifier, if this is still part of the header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Template template arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_arguments):

```
#include <memory>

template <template <class T> class AllocTemplate>
struct Tree {
  struct Node;
  using Alloc = AllocTemplate<Node>;

  [[no_unique_address]] Alloc alloc_;

  struct Deleter {
    [[no_unique_address]] Alloc alloc_;
    Deleter(const Alloc &alloc) : alloc_{alloc} {}
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T* ptr) noexcept {
      alloc_.deallocate(ptr, sizeof(T));
    }
  };
  
  struct Node {
    int val_ = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<Node, Deleter> next_;
    Node(Deleter deleter) : next_{nullptr, std::move(deleter)} 
    {}
  };

  using nodeptr = std::unique_ptr<Node, Deleter>;

  nodeptr make_node() {
      auto buf = alloc_.allocate(1);
      auto deleter = Deleter{alloc_};
      Node* node = new(buf) Node(deleter);
      return nodeptr(node, deleter);
  }
};

int main() {
    Tree<std::allocator> tree;
    [[maybe_unused]] auto node = tree.make_node();
}
```

Comment: ```CustomDeleter``` should know ```Alloc```, ```Alloc``` should know ```Node``` and ```Node``` should know ```CustomDeleter```, this is a problem

Comment: @frozenca please update your question with a minimal snippet that shows what you're trying and failing to compile. Without a snippet, your question is very unclear.

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/NBpdGq10tCpiyR4T

Comment: @frozenca would this do? https://godbolt.org/z/n5PP4WqxP

Comment: No, in ```make_node()```, ```alloc_``` should be aware of size and alignment of ```Node```

Comment: @frozenca How about this? https://godbolt.org/z/eb85jEc3n

Comment: Seems working, upvoted, thanks. I'll test it in my real use case

Comment: @frozenca please don't forget to include this snippet in your question too.